# jquery form wizard and validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i am trying to use the jquery form wizard with asp.net to create a multi step form. I have already built the form, but i am having problems during validation of emails. I have two form fields email and confirm email which should match before going to the next step. 
The problem i am having is I am using master pages and so my control id is getting renamed.The validationOptions of jquery form wizard seems to be looking at the name property of input control rather than ID, so setting clientidmode is not working as well. I am looking for suggestions or alternatives on how to make this work.

Here is my markup

```
        <label for="txtconfemail">Confirm Email</label>
   <asp:TextBox CssClass="input_field_12em" runat="server" ID="txtconfemail"  ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

Here is my javascript. This code only checks for required (not the equalTo) and even that does not work.

```
               <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        $("#myform").formwizard({
            formPluginEnabled: true,
            validationEnabled: true,
            focusFirstInput: true,
            formOptions: {
                success: function (data) { $("#status").fadeTo(500, 1, function () { $(this).html("You are now registered!").fadeTo(5000, 0); }) },
                beforeSubmit: function (data) { $("#data").html("data sent to the server: " + $.param(data)); },
                dataType: 'json',
                resetForm: true
            },
            validationOptions: {
                rules: {
                    txtconfemail : {
                        required: true

                    }
                },
                messages: {
                  txtemailconf:
                     { 
                        required:"Email is required"

                    }

               }
            }
        }
            );
    });
</script>
```

If i replace txtemailconf with ctl100$MainContent$txtconfemail, then my validation gets fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using

```
    <%= txtconfemail.UniqueID %>
```

Comment: i have already tried that as well as   $('#<%=txtemailconf.UniqueID %>') Since its inside valdationOptions, i am getting syntax error or expected identifier or string at the <%

Comment: Thank You, this worked..you pointed me in the right direction..     '<%= txtconfemail.UniqueID %>'